# Why I got out_of_range?

Tags: c++, vector

My function has to reverse the vector's values, but I got an out_of_range exception in one case. Please, explain to me what a difference between this to cases:

```
/// working version of my function
void Reverse(vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() / 2; i++)
    {
        int temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[v.size() - (i + 1)]; /// look at round brackets
        v[v.size() - (i + 1)] = temp; 
    }
}
/// wrong version
void Reverse2(vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() / 2; i++)
    {

        int temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[v.size() - i + 1];   /// this is wrong 
        v[v.size() - i + 1] = temp;   /// same
    }
}
/// 
int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 10, 22, 13, 144, 55, 167, 999};
    Reverse(v);
    for (auto c : v)
    {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Neither `v[v.size()]` nor `v[v.size() + 1]` are within the range of the vector.

Comment: What is the difference between `a - b + c` and `a - (b + c)`?

Comment: @IgorR. I noticed that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v.size() - i + 1` for when `i = 0` is the same as `v.size() - 0 + 1` or `v.size() + 1` which is clearly an out of bounds reference to `v`.

Using the parenthesis will give you `v.size() - 1`, or the last element of the vector.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for explaining. By bad:)

Answer (score 0):

Without parentheses, it is left to right evaluation.

5 - 4 + 1 = 2, 
where 5 - (4 +1) = 0.

Comment: It's quite amazing that nowadays one can study nuclear physics without knowing that...